# OpenSocial Win32 compatibility

Tags: python, opensocial

I am planning to develop an application in Python on the Win32 platform. Does the [OpenSocial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSocial) API work upon the Win32 platform as well?

To make things more clear, I need to use information from the OpenSocial API to conduct certain things in the application.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the general idea of an API is it uses a standard language like XML or JSON or whatever. You can easily find libraries that read/write those formats in most languages, no matter the platform. If you're lucky someone will have written a library for the specific API you need.

Which in this case, they have :)
http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-python-client/

Hope that helps!